# Firebase signInWithRedirect says Cannot read property 'dataset' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building the `React` application where I want my users to login with Google. My code for authentication looks like

```
import {firebaseAuth, googleProvider} from "../config/constants";

export function loginWithGoogle() {
    return authenticate(loginWithFirebase(googleProvider));
}

function authenticate(promise) {
    return promise
        .then(function (result) {
            // login with your app with result object to get accessToken (token)
            // localStorage.save(token);
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            var user = result.user;
            console.log("login happened with firebase, ", JSON.stringify(user));
            localStorage.setItem("firebaseUser", JSON.stringify(result));
            return Promise.resolve(result);
        }).catch(function(error){
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            var email = error.email;
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            console.log("failed firebase login", error);
            return Promise.reject("err");
        });
}

function loginWithFirebase(provider) {
    return firebaseAuth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    /*
     firebaseAuth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
     // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
     const token = result.credential.accessToken;
     // The signed-in user info.
     const user = result.user;
     // ...
     console.log("google login success. token=", token, ",user=", JSON.stringify(user));
     }).catch(function (error) {
     // Handle Errors here.
     const errorCode = error.code;
     const errorMessage = error.message;
     // The email of the user's account used.
     const email = error.email;
     // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
     const credential = error.credential;
     // ...
     console.log("google login failed.reason=", errorMessage);
     });
     */
}

export function logout() {
    return firebaseAuth().signOut();
}
```

When I start my app and go to http://localhost:3000, I see the button which takes me to the Google accounts to select for login to the app, but when it comes back to the app, I see error in the console which says

```
bundle.js:6106 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null
    at HTMLDocument.r (bundle.js:6106)
```

Additionally, on Mobile Safari, the click of the button does not take me anywhere.
The entire codebase is available at https://github.com/hhimanshu/react-firebase-social-authentication

Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
I made few changes based on the documentation

In `auth.js` I only do

```
export function loginWithGoogle() {
    firebaseAuth().signInWithRedirect(googleProvider);
}
```

In `Login.js`, at the top of the class (in global scope), I do

```
firebaseAuth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
    console.log("GoogleLogin Redirect result");
    if (result.credential) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // ...
    }
    // The signed-in user info.
    var user = result.user;
    console.log("user:", JSON.stringify(user));
}).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // The email of the user's account used.
    var email = error.email;
    // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
    var credential = error.credential;
    // ...
});
```

As a result, this redirection worked on the dekstop browser, but when I click on "Login with Google" on iOS Safari and iOS Chrome, nothing happens.

How can I further debug this? I pushed the latest changes to https://github.com/hhimanshu/react-firebase-social-authentication

Thanks

Comment: In the snippet you provide, signInWithRedirect is going to redirect the page, your then() logic will be interrupted.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate this a bit more?

Comment: @bojeil, please see my updated answer. I tried to fix the issue based on your comment.

Comment: Are you saying the redirect is not happening at all now or is it happening but the user is not getting signed in? Can you check the console for any errors or add a catch() when calling signInWithRedirect?

Comment: On desktop browser, redirect is happening and I can log the user, but on the iOS browser (safari and chrome), click on the button doesn't do anything. I do not know how to debug the mobile browsers :(

Comment: is signInWithRedirect throwing an error? you can catch and alert that.

Comment: @daydreamer: I notice your posts are rather chatty, I wonder if you would make them a bit more succinct? e.g. _Can someone help? I hope to get help on this. Thanks.  Any help is greatly appreciated. Could some one please help me understand. Kindly help._ etc. etc. That's a fair bit of waffle, and it will often be edited out. Would you mind?

Comment: I will edit them out. thanks